# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch when calling method dynamically

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, type-mismatch

Class Sample

belongs_to options

I have an object `x` and I am trying to do:

```
x.send "options=", z
```

but it gives me an error:

> Options expected got Hash

```
x.options.class  #=> Array
z.class          #=> Array
```

So why can't I assign the variable options directly?

P.S. `z[0].class #=> Hash` but I don't think that should matter.

Comment: What kind of object is `x`? What is the signature for its method `options=`? Or is `options` just an ActiveRecord attribute?

Comment: options is an attribute of object x which is a custom object

Comment: So object "x" has_many Options?

Comment: Actually the class of z[0] is precisely what this error is about. It's saying that it expecting a instance of option in the array  but you gave it a hash instead. Your associtations look odd to - if x.options is an array the  i would expect has_many, not belongs_to. What were you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Also that fact that you're using send is irrelevant - x.options = z would do the same - you might want to amend the title.